# SQLAlchemy sum of a column between 2 dates

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am not sure if this is possible, but I'm looking for a way to use SQLAlchemy `func.sum` on a column, but only for rows that are between 2 dates.

To make it clearer, here is the model:

```
class Income(db.Model):
    __tablename__='incomes'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    amount = db.Column(Numeric)
    user_ = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

So I'd like to do the sum of the `amount` column, but only for amount between date x and date y from the `date` column.

Is it possible with a query, or should I be better querying the whole table and working with the data afterward in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start_date, end_date = date(2014, 2, 1), date(2014, 3, 31)

q = (db.session.query(
    db.func.sum(Income.amount).label("total_amount"),)

    # @note: any of the three below should do the job:

    .filter(Income.date >= start_date).filter(Income.date <= end_date)
    # .filter(Income.date.between(start_date, end_date))
    # .filter(between(Income.date, start_date, end_date))  # first do: from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import between

)
```

Comment: That work perfectly, thanks!  I was trying with the .between but having no luck with it.

Comment: You should be able to use `between` as well. Will update the answer to include these options as well.